# Prevent gnome-pty-helper from running again

Tags: security, process, gnome, cron, process-management

I terminated the `gnome-pty-helper` process with

```
$ kill -9 9753
```

After a while it was running again with another process number.
There wasn't a restart of a system.

Why is it located under `~/.config/gnomy-pty-helper`?

```
$ file gnome-pty-helper 
gnome-pty-helper: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
```

Why is it in the crontab?

`*/10 * * * * sh -c " /home/xralf/.config/gnome-pty-helper"`

Can I delete the file and the line from the crontab? If not, why?

Comment: What does `ldd ~/.config/gnome-pty-helper` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt `/usr/bin/ldd: line 161: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: cannot execute binary file not a dynamic executable`

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it’s statically linked so there’s nothing to see there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-pty-helper` is automatically started by the VTE library when necessary. If you want to avoid its running (why?), you should avoid using anything built with the VTE library (`libvte*`).

The elements you’ve added recently make this look more like a compromise of some sort: `~/.config` shouldn’t contain binaries, and `gnome-pty-helper` certainly doesn’t belong in your `crontab`. It’s a nice name for a virus of some sort though because it wouldn’t draw attention in a process listing...

You can delete the file and the `crontab` entry (but watch out for their coming back obviously). It might be worth keeping a copy of the file somewhere safe (on a `noexec` file system) to try to figure out what it was doing...

Comment: I noticed it under `.config` because of I looked at the crontab. I would like to know more about it if it is a compromise or virus. It's in the output of netstat as well.

Comment: The size is small, only 40K. So, maybe someone could reverse engineer it and describe it.

Comment: I uploaded it here https://ufile.io/o14n2

Comment: It definitely looks iffy, it’s compressed with UPX and the ELF header has been tampered with to make disassembly harder. I haven’t had the time to look into it much further yet.

Comment: The real `gnome-pty-helper` program image lives in `/usr/lib/libvte9` or `/usr/local/libexec`.  GNOME Terminal has no need of a per-user binary, and its binary is dynamically linked.

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP, I thought that went without saying but after all it probably is worth mentioning.

Comment: There's a follow-on question to your answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382595/ .

Comment: this looks to be the same: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/07/msg00859.html (found via googling for "crontab gnome-pty-helper") so this malware has been around since at least 2012.

Comment: also: [Security Advisory: BusyWinman Linux Intrusion – July 21, 2017 15:40 PT](http://bulletins.it.ubc.ca/archives/30465)