# Gnome-pty-helper as a virus?

Tags: security, malware

I asked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334086/prevent-gnome-pty-helper-from-running-again) question and accepted the answer, where
`gnome-pty-helper` was identified as `a compromise of some sort`.

[This](https://uploadfiles.io/o14n2) is the link to the binary file.

How can I find out what was accessed on the filesystem by this binary?
How could this be prevented?

Comment: On SuperUser there is a generic question that all _How do I remove this particular virus?_ questions are pointed to, at https://superuser.com/questions/100360/ .  Perhaps Unix & Linux needs some generic _How do I identify this suspect program?_ questions.

Comment: see [Security Advisory: BusyWinman Linux Intrusion – July 21, 2017 15:40 PT](http://bulletins.it.ubc.ca/archives/30465).   Found by googling for ".config/gnome-pty-helper"

Answer (score 1):

You could upload it to a site like virustotal.com to have it analyzed.

As to how it got there, you should check logs, use the history command to search history of commands run per user, check to make sure there's no new crontab jobs, etc.

If an option, I would scrap the vm if it is a vm, or do a reinstall to make sure it's clean. Depends on what the server stores and what your company requires.